# WMIC ProcessID does not get parsed within the same command instance

Tags: command-line, batch, script, wmic, pid

I've got a batch script that I'd like to capture its Process ID but the PID is not being parsed from within the same command instance.

For example, running the batch script with the following code below will say No Instance(s) Available. But if I am to open a new command prompt and run the same WMIC command I in fact can get the PID.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "ProcessID="
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%I IN (`wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%NetworkTroubleshooter%' AND Caption Like 'cmd.exe'" GET ProcessID ^| findstr /r /v "ProcessId" 2^>nul`) DO SET "ProcessID=%%I"
IF "%ProcessID%" == "" (
    ECHO PID could not be determined.
) ELSE (
    ECHO PID is: %ProcessID%
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Within Batch Script

```
No Instance(s) Available.
PID could not be determined.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

New Command Window with the following command...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2728]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%NetworkTroubleshooter%' AND Caption Like 'cmd.exe'" GET ProcessID | findstr /r /v "ProcessId"
22860


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Do you wish a `.bat` script to capture its own process id? There are simpler methods fot that.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've tried using tasklist | findstr "TITLENAME", for example but it's just too slow causing about a 10-15 second delay which I am trying to avoid in our environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple methods for a `.bat` file finding its own process id can be found
in the post
[How to get own process pid from the command prompt in Windows](https://serverfault.com/a/1116424/18736).

Here is probably the easiest one :

```
for /F %%a in ('PowerShell -ex bypass "(gwmi Win32_Process -f ProcessID=$((gwmi Win32_Process -f ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessID)).ParentProcessID"') do set my_pid=%%a
echo %my_pid%
```

It uses PowerShell to get the PID of the grandparent process,
as the `for` introduces an extra `cmd.exe`.

You will find more methods of various kinds in the linked post.

Comment: This was it! Thank you, Harry. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```cmd
@echo off

if not "_%~2" == "_processID" =;(
     call "%~f0" networktroubleshooter processID & exit /b 
    );=

set "_%~2=" & for /f useback^tokens^=4^delims^=^<^> %%G in =;(`
     wmic.exe Process where "Name like '%%cmd.exe%%' and CommandLine like '%%^<%~1^>%%'" get %~2 /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `);= do set "_%~2=%%~G"

if not defined _%~2 =;( 
     echo\pid could not be determined. 
    );= else echo\pid is: %_processID%
```

---

**1.** Call your batch;
**2.** Checks if any arguments were passed;
**3.** If not, call again and end the first call;
**4.** If any were passed, then use them to get the PID;
**5.** Continue execution with this second bat.